# Azure Stream Analytics c# UDF on Edge using complex parameter

Tags: azure, user-defined-functions, azure-stream-analytics, azure-iot-edge

I have a scenario where a Device sends data in this format

```
[   
{
 "Metadata":{"DeviceID":"MWS55V","GatewayID":"abc1"},
 "Payload": [{"Type":"401","Data":"17.51"}],
 "Timestamp":"2018-11-01T09:33:05Z"},
{
 "Metadata":{"DeviceID":"MWS55V","GatewayID":"abc1"},
 "Payload": [{"Type":"401","Data":"18.28"}],
 "Timestamp":"2018-11-01T09:34:05Z"
}
]
```

I added [Azure Stream Analytics C# UDF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-edge-csharp-udf) 
with the idea to use the whole object as a parameter and change each `Payload.Data` based on the `Payload.Type`.

But when I try to pass `Payload` object as a parameter to the `c# UDF` an exception is thrown

> Error : ** System Exception ** ASA passed a non-supported type System.Object to be marshaled to CSharp UDF Func at variable payload

The only way it worked is if when I tried parameters of type(long, string etc).

Although this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-edge-csharp-udf-methods#supported-types-and-mapping) explicitly saying the supported types, is there a way to receive the whole object inside `c# udf` or this service is not the best for this scenario and  I need to use something else ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Payload object is an array, which is a supported type in Stream Analytics C# UDFs. Your function signature should look like:

```
public static string SampleUDF(Object[] input)
```

You should not see an error with this. Let me know if you still run into issues.

Comment: Yes, this scenario works. I also tried to pass this object as a parameter
`{
 "Metadata":{"DeviceID":"MWS55V","GatewayID":"abc1"},
 "Payload": [{"Type":"401","Data":"17.51"}],
 "Timestamp":"2018-11-01T09:33:05Z"},
{`

with `Object input` as a signature, but it throws exception.

Comment: I am not sure I fully understand. Are you trying to pass the entire incoming event into the UDF? Can you explain what you are trying to accomplish? You have to specify which fields you want to pass to the UDF.

Comment: Yes, I tried to pass the entire event. But what you said `You have to specify which fields you want to pass to the UDF.` explains why it doesn't work.